# No such DSL method 'AWS' found among steps error in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

Getting the below error while running withAWS command on jenkins inbound-agent docker container.

```
Requesting assume role
Assuming role ARN is arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/cross-account-roleAssumed role arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/cross-account-role/Jenkins-59 with id xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:Jenkins-xxxxxxxxx-59 
 [Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withAWS
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'AWS' found among steps
```

Below is the pipeline

```
stage('List staging eks cluster') {
            agent {
                label 'jenkins-jnlp'
            }
            steps {
                withAWS(roleAccount:'xxxxxxxxxx', role:'cross-account-role') {
                    AWS("--region=eu-north-1 eks list-clusters")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: According to https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-aws/ there is no `AWS` step, nor is there a step for EKS.